# Build error in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, build-error

I have deleted the files inside bin of my asp.net MVC project and while building i am getting metadata files not found error. I have tried everything. Please suggest something

Comment: ,Provide Screen Shot of Your Projects and Error

Answer (score 0):

- Clean every project individually (Right click> Clean).
- Rebuild every project individually (Right click> Rebuild).
- Rebuild the startup project.